# Using play-scalr raises Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I'm trying to use [play-scalr](http://leon.radley.se/project/play-scalr/) with Play, and have followed the install instructions on the [Github page](https://github.com/digiPlant/play-scalr), however when I make a request for a resized image I get the error:

> [RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: se/digiplant/scalr/api/Resizer$Mode : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0]

When I compiled the project, jars were downloaded, so I assume that the issue is that they were compiled using Java 1.7, but I'm trying to use them with Java 1.6:

```
$ play compile
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/brad/projects/builders/project
[info] Set current project to builders (in build file:/Users/brad/projects/builders/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/brad/projects/builders/}builders...
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/se/digiplant/play-scalr_2.10/1.0/play-scalr_2.10-1.0.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] se.digiplant#play-scalr_2.10;1.0!play-scalr_2.10.jar (2782ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/se/digiplant/play-res_2.10/1.0/play-res_2.10-1.0.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] se.digiplant#play-res_2.10;1.0!play-res_2.10.jar (2553ms)
[info] Done updating.
[success] Total time: 26 s, completed 14/04/2013 3:06:18 PM
```

Here's the versions of what I'm using:

```
$ play about
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/brad/projects/builders/project
[info] Set current project to builders (in build file:/Users/brad/projects/builders/)
[info] This is sbt 0.12.2
[info] The current project is {file:/Users/brad/projects/builders/}builders
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.0
[info] Available Plugins: play.Project, sbt.PlayProject, com.typesafe.sbteclipse.plugin.EclipsePlugin, com.typesafe.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.9.2

$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.9.2 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL

$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_43"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_43-b01-447-11M4203)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01-447, mixed mode)

$ javac -version
javac 1.6.0_43
```

Comment: You're right. Java 7 compiler "stamps" the classes with major version 51, but Java 6 requires version 50. You need to either compile with Java 6 or run with Java 7 too.

Comment: @dcernahoschi thanks for the confirmation :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up downloading the source for `play-scalr`, compiling with Java 1.6 and then putting the resulting `.jar` into my `lib/` directory.